# What is a $K$-automorphism of $L$?

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory

So when $L$ is an extension of $K$, we have that $L$ is a $K$-vectorspace. How do I determine if there is a $K$-automorphism of $L$ that takes some root to another root?

More to my main question, what do the $K$-automorphisms of $L$ look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know that this is a vector space over $K$, express elements of $L$ as linear combinations after fixing a basis. I am assuming the dimension of $L$ over $K$ is finite.  For example, if $\alpha_j$'s form a basis of $L$ express $a\in L$ as $a=\sum_j a_j\alpha_j$.  Under any $K$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ each of the $\alpha_j$'s go to an alternative root $\alpha_j'$ of a (minimal) polynomial for which $\alpha_j$ is a root. (coefficients are from $K$ and they are fixed by $\sigma$).

That is  $\sigma (a) =\sum_j a_j\alpha_j'$. This is how automorphism look like. ( You have an interesting name/id!)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. In regard to my ID, haha, I was tied between Galois in the Field and Galois in *his* field, but I opted for 'the'.